# jdbc realm, form-login-config, Tomcat and db connection error

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, authentication, web.xml

My tomcat 5.5 server has a classic FORM based authentication method with a JDBC-REALM.
Everything works fine but I would like to differentiate the login fail (wrong userId or password) from the connection error.

So I've:

> <form-login-config>
>   <form-login-page>/secure/login.jsp</form-login-page>
>   <form-error-page>/secure/errorPage.jsp</form-error-page>
>   </form-login-config>

How can I intercept a SQL-Exception rather than an incorrect login in the errorPage.jsp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this nice tutorial:
http://sportechno.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/restful-basic-http-authentication-with-tomcat-jdbcrealm/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I didn't found any help in that tutorial!